# What are containers in Aurelia Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I am familiar with Aurelia and Dependency Injection. However, I don't understand the following line from the "Learning Aurelia" book on Packtpub.com, in the Dependency Injection chapter.

> In Aurelia, a container can create child containers, which can themselves create their own children, forming a tree of containers starting from the application's root container. Each child container inherits the services of their parent, but can register their own to override their parent's.

I use DI like in the example in the book:

```
import {PersonService} from 'app-services'; 
import {Person} from 'models'; 
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework'; 

@autoinject 
export class PersonList { 

constructor(private personService: PersonService) { 
} 

getPeople(){ 
    return this.personService.getAll(); 
 } 
}
```

But where does the container fit into this?  I have not ever referenced a container in code.  I have not created any child containers. It says "Each child container inherits the services of their parent."  I have components with many child components which are separate views and viewmodels.  I don't understand how containers fit into it.  How would the viewmodels access services of the parent?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurelia has an implementation of a *dependency injection container* which it uses to instantiate viewmodels and many of the application services that are part of the framework or written by developers. Typically you do not need to use the container directly because Aurelia's system of conventions use the container to construct viewmodels and services on your behalf and the `@inject` and `@autoinject` make it unnecessary to configure the container manually.

What is a *dependency injection container*? Well a **container** is another word for an **injector**:

> The injector introduces the services into the client. Often, it also constructs the client. An injector may connect together a very complex object graph by treating an object like a client and later as a service for another client. The injector may actually be many objects working together but may not be the client. The injector may be referred to by other names such as: assembler, provider, container, factory, builder, spring, construction code, or main.
>   --https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Aurelia's container system is hierarchical, which means when you `@inject` or `@autoinject` something, the current (child) container will be searched for the item and if it's not found, the parent container will be searched and so on, until the item is found or the root container is hit, in which case Aurelia will construct a new instance of the requested item.

In your code snippet you have:

```ts
import {PersonService} from 'app-services'; 
import {Person} from 'models'; 
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework'; 

@autoinject 
export class PersonList { 

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) { 
  } 

  getPeople(){ 
    return this.personService.getAll(); 
  } 
}
```

Assuming this is a custom element's view-model which you are using like this: `<person-list></person-list>`, here's what will happen when Aurelia instantiates the `PersonList`.

1. A child container will be created from the current container (more on what the "current container is" later). Equivalent of calling `container.createChildContainer()`. We'll call this child container "`childContainer`".
2. Contextual items will be registered in the child container such as the DOM element (the view) for the PersonList viewmodel. This is the equivalent of calling `childContainer.registerInstance(Element, personListDomElement)`. Why? Because this enables developers to `@inject(Element)` (or the `@autoinject` equivalent).
3. Once the child container is configured, it's used to create an instance of the `PersonList`. Equivalent of calling:

   ```
   personList = childContainer.invoke(PersonList);
   childContainer.registerInstance(PersonList, personList);
   ```
4. The child container doesn't have anything registered with the key "`PersonService`" so it's parent container will be searched, until it's found or cannot be found, in which case Aurelia will construct a new instance of `PersonService` and register it in the root container so the instance can be reused in subsequent lookups.
5. The person list viewmodel and view are composed by the templating engine and the created, bind, attached, etc lifecycle events happen.

Bonus: earlier I mentioned *a child container will be created from the current container*... Every Aurelia application has a "root level" container that every child container descends from, directly or indirectly. Aurelia's core application services are registered in the root container: the `BindingEngine`, `ObserverLocator`, `TaskQueue` and many more. This is what enables developers to write `@inject(TaskQueue)` and get the same TaskQueue instance that the Aurelia framework is using internally. Anyways, when a custom element or custom attribute is instantiated a child container is used to create the custom element or custom attribute. If that custom element contains other custom element a child container will be created from the current child container and used to instantiate the child custom element and so on. In other words, the "current container" depends on how deep your component is in a hierarchy of nested custom elements and custom attributes.

Links:

- https://www.danyow.net/inversion-of-control-with-aurelia-part-1/
- https://www.danyow.net/inversion-of-control-with-aurelia-part-2/
- http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/dependency-injection/latest/dependency-injection-basics

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you won't need to directly reference the container. Aurelia will handle that for you when it needs to instantiate your components (pages, custom elments, custom attributes, value converters, etc).

The DI Container can be thought of as a family tree. There is one app-level container that all other containers are children of. Each component gets a new child container created for it.

There are helpers you can use to give the container information about how it should handle things. You get the default behavior by using `@autoinject`, but if you need to be more specific, you can switch over to the `@inject` decorator and do things like `@inject(Parent.of(Foo), Optional.of(Bar))` or something. This would give you an instance of the `Foo` class that was created in the parent container, and will tell the container, "I'd like to have an instance of Bar, but it's cool if you can't create it for me."

If you need access to the parent's VM, you can use `Parent.of()` to get it in a child component. Note that this is one of those "Handle with care" type things, because you are tying a child component directly to the implementation of the Parent's VM, and the component will fail to create (and possibly crash the app) if you use it inside a page/component that has a different VM class.

For more information, please check out our docs: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/dependency-injection/latest/dependency-injection-basics